# Output buffering and AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, jquery, output-buffering

When a user clicks a button on my site, a particular part of a page will be refreshed, but it takes a while to render the entire section. Is it possible to  display/output parts of the section in real time rather than wait for the entire section to finish? How would i do this if im sending it as an ajax request for html content? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend setting `cache: true` in your AJAX call (if using jQuery) and either way, you're going to want to set the HTTP response headers. [Here are some examples.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7950882/what-are-the-caching-techniques-that-can-be-implemented-while-developing-a-dynam/7950982#7950982) By setting the `cache-control` headers and `expires` etc, your AJAX requests - if unchanged - will be loaded from cache instead.  This will drastically speed things up.

A quick example:

```
if (!headers_sent()) {
    // seconds, minutes, hours, days
    $expires = 60*60*24*14;
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Cache-Control: maxage=' . $expires);
    header('Expires: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time() + $expires) . ' GMT');
}
```

Note: this will not work with POST requests, just GET.

Comment: i can catch certain html contents in a user's browser? How would i do this with httpd.conf file? Also, my content is dynamic so im not sure if caching is appropriate.

Comment: Yes you can. Do you have access to modify the .htaccess file? I would say change these settings _there_ instead of directly modifying the apache config. Either way, check out the link I put in my answer (where it says "here are some examples").

Answer (score 0):

As said, caching your AJAX requests is a good option. Besides that, all I think you can to do make your application seem faster is to show users a [progressbar](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Progressbar) while (re)loading content with AJAX.

Comment: You could also use the new HTML5 `<progress>` tag ;)

Comment: hmmm... so there isn't any way to display the content as it is being process through ajax?

Comment: if this for client's site for any professional site whatsoever then don't use HTML5, not enough support for it yet. That is unless you don't care about IE then by all means ha

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a Pagelets technique. Essentially you could work this in a way, like below:

```
index.html
  Ajax -> load content from PHP script which outputs the navigation bar
  Ajax -> load content from PHP script which outputs the body
```

And have several different Ajax calls loading each different part of your site. This does have a disadvantage of increasing the amount of HTTP requests the user's browser has to make, however.

This is presuming though that different parts can be generated separately from the rest of the page. If all your content needs to be generated at the same time then this technique will be of no use to use.

This is of a good read (Facebook project named "BigPipe"): http://www.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=389414033919